# About Y-axis scale in amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I am facing problem with scale on vertical axis like 2,4,6,8,10 etc or 5,10,15,20. I have achieved this on one axis (name Iron in ppm) but how to achieve this on second y-axis?

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",

        "id": "SweepGraph",
        "legend": {
            "marginTop": 150,
            "useGraphSettings": true
        },
        "synchronizeGrid": synchronizeGridFlag,
        "dataProvider": SortedChartData,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "id": "BaseNumber",
            "axisColor": "#0000ff",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "position": "right",
            "title": "BaseNumber in mgKOH/g",
            "minimum" : BaseNumberMinimum,
            "maximum": BaseNumberMaximum,
            "autoGridCount": false,
            "gridCount": 100,
            "synchronizationMultiplier": ironLabelFrequency,
            "strictMinMax": true,
            //"synchronizationMultiplier": BaseNumberLabelFrequency
        }, {
            "id": "Iron",
            "maximum": IronMaximum,
            "minimum": IronMinimum,
            "minMaxMultiplier": 0,
            "precision": 0,
            "synchronizationMultiplier": ironLabelFrequency,
            "synchronizeWith": "BaseNumber",
            "strictMinMax": true,
            "axisAlpha": 1,
            "axisColor": "#ff0000",
            "axisThickness": 2,
            "gridCount": 100,
            "gridThickness": 0,
            "minHorizontalGap": 0,
            "minVerticalGap": 0,
            "title": "Iron in ppm"
        }],
        "graphs": AmCharts.parseJSON(graphData),
        "chartScrollbar": {},
        "chartCursor": {
            "cursorPosition": "pointer",
            "oneBalloonOnly": true,
            "valueZoomable":true
        },
        "guides":GlobalSweepGuides,
        "categoryField": "FeedRate",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "title": "ACC Value in (g/Kw/h)/(%wt)",
            "axisColor": "#DADADA",
            "minorGridEnabled": true,
            "autoGridCount": false,
            "gridCount": 12
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": true,
            "menu": [],
            "libs": {
                "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/libs/"
            },
            "position": "bottom-right"
        }
});
```

Here is jsFiddle url:https://jsfiddle.net/HARSHAD557/jgz289fw/

Please solve this problem.

Comment: Please format your answer and delete unnecessary code parts! Besides that the scale in your fiddle seems to work fine. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried already? Please read [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to see how to make a good, answerable question on SO.

Comment: on first axis its working using synchronizedmultiplier but second axis not working like different gap between labels like 15,30,45 on first axis and 3,6,9,12 on second axis

Comment: The code in the fiddle is a bit different than the code you posted here. To synchronize the scales 1:1 just use `"synchronizationMultiplier": 1` in the iron axis

Comment: but i want different difference in labels on iron and basenumber axis like in iron axis have labels 2,4,6,8 etc and basenumber axis have labels 5,10,15,20

Comment: Aha. Thats the information that is needed IN the question. Again, please read [THIS](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for future questions. `"synchronizationMul‌​tiplier": 0.2` will change the scale to 2,4,6,...

Comment: but this for only one axis, i want at time iron "synchronizationMul‌​‌​tiplier":0.2 and basenumber "synchronizationMul‌​‌​tiplier":0.3

Comment: Axis synchronization doesn't work like this. You have to set the grid count on one axis and then you can have the other axis adjust its scale based on the multiplier.

Comment: please give example about that in valueaxes array